# Jquery como selecionar um elemento especifico pelo index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Gostaria de saber como selecionar um elemento especifico pela posição do index, pois consigo percorrer a estrutura com as funções next e prev, mas não estou encontrando uma forma de selecionar um elemento diretamente pela posição dele.
Estou utilizando Jquery

```
function proximo()
{
    if($(".elemento").next().size())
    {                              
       $(".elemento").fadeOut().removeClass("elemento").next().
           fadeIn(1000).addClass("elemento");              

      var texto = $(".elemento").attr("alt");
      $("#slide p").hide().html(texto).delay(500).fadeIn();
    }
}
```

Comment: `$(".ativo")[i]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Existem duas possibilidades:**

- O pseudo selector `:eq(numero)` [<sub>(mais info em Inglês)</sub>](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)
- O método `.eq(numero)` [<sub>(mais info em Inglês)</sub>](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

**Exemplo:**

```
$('li:eq(1)').css('color', 'blue');
$('li').eq(2).css('color', 'red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sfdpq/

---

Se já tiver uma coleção de elementos e quiser escolher um deles atravé do index pode usar `.index(numero)`

Por exemplo:

```
$('li').click(function(){
   this.innerHTML = $(this).index(); // vai mudar o texto para o numero do index
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sfdpq/1/

---

Pode sempre usar javascript simples, tendo em conta que uma coleção é tipo array, usando `$(variosElementos)[numero]`. Mas atênção que desta maneira retorna-lhe um objeto `raw` (apetece-me traduzir para "crú"...), mas no fundo um objeto sem os metodos jQuery adicionados.

Comment: perfeito funcionou corretamente, muito obrigado pela ajuda.  $("#slide img:eq("+numero+")").fadeIn(1000).addClass("elemento");